# Excel sheet not showing on desktop version of excel but it is showing on teams

Tags: excel, microsoft-teams

This morning I created a sheet on Excel and now when I open that workbook on teams I can see my new sheet but then when I press "Open on desktop version" it has disappeared. I checked and it is not hidden so I don't know how to recover it.

I also tried going into file -> info -> Version history. but it only lets me refresh to one minute ago so that's not working either. I am not sure of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out to us. We are the developer support team for Microsoft teams focused on helping developers resolve their code issues. For issues related to teams product, please reach out to the [Product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.